# If the universe begins and ends sequentially but time only exists inside the fabric, then everything must have always existed

Tags: time, universe

Can you the reader refute my logic, that if time isn't existing externally outside of the big bang processes, and we know that this has a beginning and end sequentially, then everything we experience has never reached a certain point, it has always existed.

In other words, everything just is and has always has been this "is".

The ultimate faith of the universe is well established in physics and it assumes some sort of end in the model (Heath death, big freeze, big bounce, big rip). Furthermore it assumes a beginning in the model as well. But no time passage outside of these processes.

And so nothing outside of these two fundamental events can exist if there is no passage of time to account for anything else occurring.

In other words, there is no time for anything else to have been in process prior to the big bang. Nor is there any need in physics to have any additional events for the equations to be consistent and time symmetric

Are the premises sound?  Is it the case that time depends on the Big Bang?
Even if not sound, is the logic valid?  We would need to spell out premises and conclusion.

Premise:  No time before Big Bang
Premise:  Time has a beginning and end
Conclusion:  Everything that exists has and will always continue to exist

Comment: The "beginning" and "ultimate fate" are just extrapolations of the pattern from the *observable* part of the universe based on *local* models. They do not assume "no time passage" outside, and some of their extensions assume the opposite, like [brane cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology#Models_of_brane_cosmology). Regardless, "nothing outside can exist if there is no passage of time to account for anything else" is a non-sequitur. There is no unified time in relativity and time may be a derivative concept in quantum theory. Its "passing" is not required for "else".

Comment: Perhaps the absence of the past does not indicate how time is defined there.

Comment: I don't see the logical connective between the assumption that time does not exist outside of the universe and the conclusion that everything always existed.  Perhaps you can edit that in?

Comment: Hawkings claims that questions about what before the big bang amounts to what is north of the north pole. Regardless of whether something can reside outside of any time model, physicists claim that it's a dead end. And so I don't need an absence of absolute time for my argument, but it doesnt' hurt

Comment: "I don't see the logical connective between the assumption that time does not exist outside of the universe and the conclusion that everything always existed. Perhaps you can edit that in?" If there's an infite past, then it would take an infinite time to reach this point. So there is no infinite past. If the past is not infinite, but had no special date of beginning, then it logically has always existed

Comment: "The ultimate **faith** of the universe " ???

Comment: "There is no time for anything else to have been in process prior to the big bang." Yes, if time is born with the universe, there is no "prior" to time.

Comment: Hawking's comment applied to his, with Hartle, ["no boundary" model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartle%E2%80%93Hawking_state). This model explicitly postulates regions of the universe "outside" of the Big Bang spacetime. So do currently popular models with  other regions where "time passes" ([inflationary multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation#Inflation,_eternal_inflation,_and_the_multiverse)), and those where it even passes before and after the current expansion cycle ([ekpyrotic/cyclic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe)).

Answer (score -1):

There is an inherent assumption...

... that "chirality"/handedness, and the "[right-hand-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Righthand_head_rule&oldid=1169151571)" are universal.

Not local and emergent phenomenon.

If you want complete logic about the nature of time and the universe, then you may want to double-check that assumption... and whether you can logically support assuming it to be true.

We could go with "Wikipedia says the right-hand-rule is universal"... but... ya know... sometimes it is worth digging a little deeper than Wikipedia.